# Wifi Default Gateway changes automatically after a few seconds

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, dhcp

I am having a strange issue. Until now I was using ethernet with static IP. But now I decided to go along with DHCP reservation and wifi. At the same time I have also decided to change range and from 192.168.1.0/24, i moved now to 192.168.2.0/24.

DHCP reservation and ethernet works perfectly! The problem starts when I try to use it with wifi.

My network details are 192.168.2.254/24 gw 192.168.2.1.

When I connect to wifi, I see that I am getting the proper IP & GW. After a few second I check again and my GW is changes to 192.168.1.1 and there are also a couple new routes in my routing table.

The end result is no internet connection. If I try to remove the routes and and a new GW it works again and somehow it is changed on its own automatically.

On the same system I have another ubuntu installation which DOES NOT have the same problem, so I guess it has to do with setting static GW to 192.168.1.1 and now it is kept somewhere and I cannot reset it.

Any suggestion as to where this configuration maybe laying???

Answer (score 0):

I had the same (or very similar) problem. After lots of search, it turned out to be a DHCP daemon running on the same system. You can check if the output of `ps -ef | grep -i dhcp` mentions just `/sbin/dhclient` (that's ok) or also `/sbin/dhcpcd` (that shouldn't be running). If so, you can stop it with `sudo systemctl status dhcpcd` and disable it with `sudo systemctl disable dhcpcd`.

As for how/why was the daemon running, in my case it was most likely due to an old [pi-hole](https://pi-hole.net/) installation that wasn't completely uninstalled.